# Counting attributes in a model where the object to be counted changes often

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

For the given scenario i need to count the amount of `items` in a given field. Below should reflect better.

```
resource = {
     name1 : [1,2,3,4],
     name2 : [a,b,c]
}
```

but sometimes it will look like

```
resource = [1, 2, c, 8]
```

what i am struggling to grasp is how i can get the total amount of items for each occasion in one function. I am comfortable with how to do it for either but i need to try and make a function that will accept both and return the outcome i am looking for.

for this example the first scenario would be 7 `items`, and the second would return 4 `items`

Comment: why not use if else by checking if resource is an `array`

Comment: just trying to keep things as tidy as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided by [@OriDrori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori) works for a given example. If you add a layer of deepness, it stops working.

```js
const resource1 = {
     name1 : [1,2,3,4],
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
}

const resource2 = [1, 2, 'c', 8];

const resource3 = {
     subResource: {
       name1 : [1,2,3,4]
     },
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
};

const countItems = (obj) => [].concat(...Object.values(obj)).length;

console.log(countItems(resource1)); // 7

console.log(countItems(resource2)); // 4

console.log(countItems(resource3)); // 4 Instead of 7
```

Instead, you should make a recursive function (a function that calls itself) to handle any level of deepness.

```js
const resource1 = {
     name1 : [1,2,3,4],
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
}

const resource2 = [1, 2, 'c', 8];

const resource3 = {
     subResource: {
       name1 : [1,2,3,4]
     },
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
};

const resource4 = {
     subResource: {
       subsubResource: {
         name1 : [1,2,3,4]
       }
     },
     name1 : [1,2,3,4],
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
};

const countItems = (obj) => {
  let total = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) { total += obj.length; }
  else {
   for (const key in obj) {
     total += countItems(obj[key]);
   }
  }
  
  return total;
};

console.log(countItems(resource1)); // 7
console.log(countItems(resource2)); // 4
console.log(countItems(resource3)); // 7
console.log(countItems(resource4)); // 11
```

Comment: Thankfully where i get this from is very strict so there will not be any levels past the example but thanks for getting me thinking about recursive functions as i 100% need this else where.

Comment: @dince12 sure, no problem !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()`, and `Array.concat()` to convert the properties of the `resource` object to a single array. This won't effect the `resource` array. Then get the length.

```js
const resource1 = {
     name1 : [1,2,3,4],
     name2 : ['a','b','c']
}

const resource2 = [1, 2, 'c', 8];

const countItems = (obj) => [].concat(...Object.values(obj)).length;

console.log(countItems(resource1)); // 7

console.log(countItems(resource2)); // 4
```